# How to split a list of objects on the basis of two criteria in optimized way?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, knapsack-problem, partition-problem

I have a list of objects say `bag` which has `Quantity`, `Volume` and `weight`. I want to split or join multiple object on the user input which will be `max weight` and `max volume` , So we want to split the list of `bag` further into more `bag` which has maximum weight and maximum volume provided by the user in best way so that no weight and volume of bag is left.
What I have achieved so far is, splitting the `bag` according to `volume` or `weight`, So first I split according to `weight` and that's totally optimized but when I apply same algorithm to split `volume` the split is not best.
Algorithm I applied:

1. Insert all the `bag` in priority queue
2. Take the first element with least weight per quantity and insert it into a bag.
3. If the bag is full, create a new bag or else poll the next bag and insert that also.
4. If a bag can't be inserted completely then divide the quantity and insert the quantity that can be inserted and leave the rest as it is in the priority queue.

bag.class

```
public class bag {
    int quantity; 
    int weightPerQty;
    int volumePerQty;
  }
```